# SQL запрос. Please help

Tags: mysql, sql

есть две таблицы: BOOKS и COMMENTS, а также массив ID(более 100).
Table BOOKS :+ ID_BOOKS + ID_EBOOKS +
TABLE COMMENTS:  + ID  + MARK +

Нужно получить среднюю оценку с таблицы COMMENTS соответств. ID, где не известно какая книга (EBOOK || BOOK) соответствует ID . Еще средняя оценка выводится на основе связки ID_BOOKS и ID_EBOOKS, т.е если ID соответствует ID_BOOKS - то средняя оцека с таблицы COMMENTS нужна ID_BOOKS и ID_EBOOKS. Все сделать одним запросом. ПОМОГИТЕ PLEASE !!!!

Comment: вопрос приведите в порядок, ничего же не понятно

Comment: Причина закрытия "непонятна суть вопроса" в тему как никогда. Вам самому понятно, что вы написали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select AVG(C.MARK) as Average
from COMMENTS as C join BOOKS as B
   on B.ID_BOOKS=C.ID or B.ID_EBOOKS =C.ID
where B.ID_BOOKS=1
```